# Going back from inner screen to parent screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a stack navigator structure like this

index.js -> App.js -> LoginStck, HomeNavStack 
From LoginStck on successful login I go to HomeNavStack
and from while doing this I reset the stack to have only HomeNavStack(did that to avoid login screen when going back) In HomeStack there are 4 tabs  namely Home/Payment/Profile/More with separate stack for each tab. I navigate to MoreScreen within More tab and won logout I need to go to Login Stack(the very first one discarding all other screen).

I did try this`

```
dothis = async () => {
const someAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'HomeNavigatorNew'})
  ]
});
this.props.navigation.navigate(someAction)

}
```

but didn't work. Any insights....??
Thanks in Advance

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommend way to switch between Login and other screens is by using `createSwitchNavigator`.

For more information please check:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html#docsNav

I created a simple example that can be helpful for your case:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  createStackNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createSwitchNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

class LoginScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>LoginScreen</Text>
          <Button
              title={'Login'}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeStack')}
          />
        </View>
    )
  }
}

class PaymentScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>PaymentScreen</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

class ProfileScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>ProfileScreen</Text>
        </View>
    )
  }
}

class MoreScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
          <Text>MoreScreen</Text>
          <Button
              title={'Logout'}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('LoginStack')}
          />
        </View>
    )
  }
}

const PaymentStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Payment: PaymentScreen,
    }
);

const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Profile: ProfileScreen,
    }
);

const MoreStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      More: MoreScreen,
    }
);

const HomeStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
      PaymentStack: PaymentStack,
      ProfileStack: ProfileStack,
      MoreStack: MoreStack,
    }
);

const LoginStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Login: LoginScreen,
    }
);

export default createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      LoginStack: LoginStack,
      HomeStack: HomeStack,
    }
);
```

Comment: thanks for CreateSwitchNavigator. But I was looking for navigation from logout to login. I tried different codes but none of them are working